# Stop and Resume issue with stage.frameRate

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I use stage.frameRate for stop and resume the game.The game menu down on stage to  when click the pause button.But when I click stop button it not work until I moving the mouse.How can I fix that.Thanks

```
stopa.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{

fa.y+=asagi;
ban.y+=banasagi;
playa.y+=asagi;

if (fa.y>=fa.height/0.0) {
    asagi*=-2;
}   

if (ban.y>=ban.height/0.0) {
    banasagi*=-2;
}   

if (playa.y>=playa.height/0.0) {
    asagi*=-2;
}   
stage.frameRate = 0.01;
}
 
//Resume Button
playa.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onaClick);
function onaClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
timercheck.stop();

  fa.y+=yukari;
  ban.y+=banyukari;
  playa.y+=yukari;

if (fa.y>=fa.height/0.0) {
    yukari*=-2;
}

    if (ban.y>=ban.height/0.0) {
    banyukari*=-2;
}

        if (playa.y>=playa.height/0.0) {
    yukari*=-2;
}
stage.frameRate = 24;
}
```

Comment: Do not use frame rate to control pause function. Very bad practice because .01 seconds is a terrible response time and when that is what your frame rate is, the user will give some input, flash will accept it, and then in 100 seconds, the next frame will tick and the input will be processed. This makes getting out of the paused state feel very sluggish. Instead you should have a Boolean variable hold the state of the game and a function toggle that value. Good luck.

Comment: How can I hold the state of the game ?  I use boolean and simply: if pause true removeEventListener else addevent....But problem is my object use random movement and it resume from another position when I resume.Game must resume from last paused state.

Comment: @KucuKeko. just think about what it means to pause. Things are dynamic (always changing) because of what..? EnterFrame? Timer? gotoAndPlay? What happens if your pause function just **stop timers**, use `...Stop` instead of `...Play`on MovieClips, use `removeEventListener` for any  **enterframe** codes? When things have stopped you can show appropriate menu/text like "Paused press to resume"...

Comment: I use enterframe but I fix it.I put all addeventlistener in one function and use boolean variable.And buttons keep move from where is paused.Thanks.

Comment: ...Please incorporate .stop() and .play()

Comment: I've just spent the last a week for that.I tried boolean and removeeventlistener.But this is caused too many problems.

Can I change speed only for pause menu movieclip ? How can I fix that ? Thanks